# Is it possible to convert from 2D to 3D form?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, opencv, 3d, matlab-cvst

I have captured car positions at different frames from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukMFR0IQ3Yc).
**Suppose car's**(e.g.left side car which is coming towards us in the images) **centroid  at video frame1 is P(x1,y1) and Q(x2,y2) at video frame4.**

**Is it possible to represent P and Q points into 3D? so that i can calculate correct pixel distance d(PQ) and finally compute actual distance**

Note:u can assume that camera is stationary, placed at height 10 m from ground level .u can also assume any suitable data if u want [image: car moving on road]
also u can refer the next figure also.

[image: side view and front view]

Comment: Marking 50% of your questions bold, really doesn't help.

Comment: @jojek sir i have added one figure for reference

Answer (score 5):

[EDITED] Here's how it's done.

Steps:
1. Isolate the Road Divider Part.

[image: Cropped Image][image: Isolate the Yellow strips]

Then, using Houghlines, find out the longest lines in Image. Find out the extrema points that cross image boundary. You got the Quadilateral points. I skipped this part by Manually Choosing them. In my case, the width of road at top of image is 10, and at bottom is 60.

[image: The Quadilateral to Transform]

Now, for the Destination, we have to Image so that Divider Quadilateral has uniform width of 60, so we save in another array new points, which have same bottom points, but top points are modified as they form a rectangle with height same as image (or bigger, you can adjust as it suits you after running it once and seeing the results), but width 60. Remember, we are transforming our image such that the divider fits into this Rectangular Area. Image will change automatically.

Now, using 
`Mat TransformMat = getPerspectiveTransform(ipPts, opPts);`

of opencv on initial and destination quadilateral Points, we get a Transform Matrix, Which we apply to our Test Image.

`warpPerspective(ipImg, opImg, TransformMat, ipImg.size());`

[image: Transformed Image]

You'll see a lot of Area is Cropped to fit the Output in InputImage Size. However you'll notice that Image is Transformed to get parallel Divider, as we Expected. By performing some Translation and Stuff, and taking a bigger Size Output Image, You'll get this. We can never get a perfectly wrapped Output Image, since its size can be very large. But we'll reach some constraint that'll fulfill our task. Here's Last image :

[image: Final Tansformed Image]

Comment: @A Matlabber sir in Matlab is there any function to convert from 2d to 3d projection.??

Comment: Your problem is not a 2d to 3d projection problem. Its a problem of Homographic transformation and Perspective Mapping, then further processing that 'll help you to compute distance(what you are trying to accomplish by making a '3d').

Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961179/generate-a-top-dow-view-of-a-road-using-warpperspective-opencv) discussion may help you with it.

Comment: @A Matlabber sir its getting difficult to understand Homographic transformation and Perspective Mapping.i searched on google,but not getting idea about it..

Comment: You can google for several examples of Homographic Transformation and Perspective Mapping. This is an introductory topic, which is taught in many of computer vision online courses. I'm quite busy right now, else I would have gave you some refrences about them. Try looking for courses on Image Processing/Computer Vision, they seldom have demonstration/programming exercise on *such* type of problems.

Comment: @A Matlabber ok ,i will do as u say.thank u.

Comment: @A Matlabber sir i trying reading about perspective mapping but i am confused that how should i treat the Z axis.means we  assume any standard value as focal length of camera.then how should we move forward to compute X,Y and Z co-ordinates?

Comment: I am adding the implementation above.

Comment: @A Matlabber thank sir for your feedback ,i will look at what u explained above and if i get any doubt ,i will disturb u again.. ;-)

Comment: Yeah sure..I'll be happy to :P

btw here's the code and files, in case of doubt. http://goo.gl/Ta36jp

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a sort of [ray tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29) problem. If you know the position and orientation of your camera you should be able to calculate the [3x4 projection matrix](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/EPSRC_SSAZ/node3.html) and its inverse.

This should allow you to convert from image points to 3d position (on the road). This discussion http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/2D-to-3D-projection-with-given-plane-td7272428.html might have more useful information.

As for applying it in matlab. There is an [affine3d](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/affine3d-class.html) which you can use for storing the transform. There might also be useful things for projections/ray-tracing in the file exchange such as http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25974-raytracer but I haven't looked in detail to find what is relevant for what you want.

Comment: sir its getting difficult to understand Homographic transformation and Perspective Mapping.i searched on google also links u given,but not getting idea about it..

Comment: @sagar Look up for "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" from Hartley & Zisserman. This is THE book explaining homography in a natural way (using homogeneous coordinates, in which the transform is linear).

Answer (score 1):

If you can calibrate your camera, and if you can detect some reference points on the road surface, then you can get 3D coordinates of the image points that are on the road.  This assumes that the road is on a plane.  In other words, if you can detect a car, then you can calculate the 3D coordinates of the bottom of the car.  See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/measuring-planar-objects-with-a-calibrated-camera.html) in MATLAB using the Computer Vision System Toolbox.